Does a sandboxed iFrame not set cookies?
I've been working on a solution that requires an embedded sandboxed iFrame that makes a call to a different origin endpoint. The requirement is to ensure that the iFrame is sandboxed with only allow-scripts permission. On a response from the endpoint, the iFrame will postMessage, then be removed from the dom. The endpoint should return and set a cookie on its own origin using the response header set-cookie. I want to confirm whether this embedded iframe will be able to set cookies on this origin for all scopes (not limited to the iframe and the cookie should be accessible to the parent frame) and whether the cookie will be deleted once the iframe is deleted? If the frame can set cookies, how is this possible - given this and this overflow article, it seems like sandboxed iframes should not have read or write permissions to cookies?
In a small test simulation that I did, where the parent page and the embedded iframe live on different domains (and the iframe is sandboxed to only allow-scripts), the embedded iframe did set the cookie despite being sandboxed. Is this expected behavior? If not, what are some causes that may be resulting in the iframe being allowed to set cookies?
Any guidance or references is appreciated!
